# how to format the underscore.js result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

I need to remove the key from the underscore.js result.

I grouped an array,this is the result I got for underscore.js:

```
{ '20': [ { Employee: 'ved', id: 20 }, { Employee: 'p', id: 20 }],
  '25': [ { Employee: 'ved', id: 25 } ] }
```

I tried this _.without method , but it won't work .

From the above result object, I need to remove the keys, i.e. `20` and `25`.

I should look like:

```
[ [ { Employee: 'ved', id: 20 },
    { Employee: 'p', id: 20 }
  ], 
  [
    { Employee: 'ved', id: 25 }
  ]
]
```

Comment: post the result that you want

Comment: You can use `Object.values()`

Comment: [ [ { Employee: 'ved', id: 20 }, { Employee: 'p', id: 20 }],
   [ { Employee: 'ved', id: 25 } ] ] @AyushGupta this is the result i want

Comment: What is the actual input? What is the expected output?

Comment: Please update your question, do not post expansion to your question as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)

```js
var data = { '20': [ { Employee: 'ved', id: 20 }, { Employee: 'p', id: 20 }],'25': [ { Employee: 'ved', id: 25 } ] },
    result = Object.values(data);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object.values()` is what you need to use, like this:

```js
let input = { '20': [ { Employee: 'ved', id: 20 }, { Employee: 'p', id: 20 }], '25': [ { Employee: 'ved', id: 25 } ] };

console.log(Object.values(input));
```